# How to set initialValue with semantic-ui-redux-form-fields

Tags: redux-form, semantic-ui-react, semantic-ui-redux-form-fields

I'm trying to create an Edit form w/ [`semantic-ui-redux-form-fields`](https://github.com/artisin/semantic-ui-redux-form-fields). The forms work fine w/ a blank starting point, but for an edit form where I have initial values, I haven't been able to get it to work.

If I'm using straight `redux-form`, this works fine for initializing the form as long as I have a `prop` of `initialValues` passed into my form component.

Using that logic, I would think to all I would need to do is change the `Field#component` attribute from `"input"` to `{Input}` (/w the appropriate import). Note that I never see `currentValue` being passed in via `props`. It's not clear how this prop would ever get populated.

*Props:*

```
{initialValues: {"first_name": "Bob"}}
```

*Working Component:*

```
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { reduxForm, Field} from 'redux-form'

...

return <Field component="input" type="text" name='first_name'/>
```

*Not Working Component:*

```
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { reduxForm, Field} from 'redux-form'
import { Input } from 'semantic-ui-redux-form-fields'

...

return <Field component={Input} type="text" name='first_name'
              currentValue={this.props.currentValue}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Input` component in `semantic-ui-react` has a `defaultValue` prop that I believe you should be able to use to initialize the `Field` with data since you are passing it the `Input` in it's `component` prop.

```
<Field 
  component={Input}
  defaultValue={this.props.currentValue}
  name='first_name'
  type='text' 
/>
```

Comment: I think the point of the `semantic-ui-redux-form-fields` is to keep `redux-form` in charge of the state, so they only use `currentValue`.  The `defaultValue` _would_ get passed to `Input`, but I'm not sure what the impact would be. We're no longer using SUI-redux-FF, so /shrug. If we did do this, we might want to use `defaultValue={this.props.initialValue[fieldName]}` instead since default ~= initial

Comment: @Snekse in my example above, this is actually what we use in my current project to achieve what you were asking for. This still keeps `redux-form` in charge of the content in `redux` state, as you correctly pointed out is the whole point of using `semantic-ui-redux-form-fields` or similar tooling.